# Php cant recognize ">" simbol

Tags: php, apache

I have a weird problem, in my code when I try to include another file, it doesn't recognize it because the **">"** symbol in any part of my code. I'm running my code in an Ubuntu server with lamp. The problem is just in the new server, i have already running my code in other servers and never got this kind of error.

This is my example code, just include another file in 
test.php

```
<?php

//these 2 lines are just for output reference doesn´t affect the code
echo "Existe :: ". file_exists("Connection2.php")."<p>"; // Output :: Existe 1
echo "Es leible ::" . is_readable("Connection2.php")."<p>"; //Output :: Existe 1
include_once 'Connection2.php';   

?>
```

The Connection2.php files is in the same directory and the code is:

```
<?php

/**
* Los parametros de conexión se encuentran en el archivo    
dbCredentials.php    en lib > db
* Podemos mandar conexiones personalizadas llenando los parámetros opcionales
* @author pitler
*/
class Connection2 
{

 public $connection;

/**
 * Nombre de la clase
 * @var String Nombre de la clase
 */
private $className;


function __construct()
{
    $this->className = "Connection2";
}   
}


?>
```

When I run test.php I don't have an error, it just includes the content of the file but after the **">"** sign in the comment block where it says : lib > db and the output is ::

```
Existe :: 1

Es leible ::1

db * Podemos mandar conexiones personalizadas llenando los parámetros opcionales * @author pitler */ class Connection2 { public $connection; /** * Nombre de la clase * @var String Nombre de la clase */ private $className; function __construct() { $this->className = "Connection2"; } } ?>
```

The file exists and is readable. 
As you can see, it just includes all the text of my Connection2.php file after the ">" sign in the comments block.

If I take out the ">" symbol of my comments block, the results is ::

```
Existe :: 1

Es leible ::1

className = "Connection2"; } } ?>
```

As you can see, now it gets the content of Connection.php but after it finds the ">" that is when i assign the variable `$this->className = "Connection2";`, the result is the text after that.

Any suggestions ????

Comment: Do you have the code enclosured inside `<?php` and `?>` in the class file?

Comment: Yes, all the code is inside the tags, i have already update the code in the example

Answer (score 4):

You're missing opening `<?php` tags in all of your files.

If you don't have an opening `<?php` tag, the entire file is assumed to be in HTML context. Everything in the file will be dumped to the browser.

Comment: in addition to this his `html` markup is wrong `echo "<p>Existe :: ". file_exists("Connection2.php")."</p>";` would be the correct way to open and close his `<p>` tags

Comment: I have the openning and close php tag in all my files, i dont put it in the example, just the code but the files has it.  So thats not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i made changes to the configuration files of the bitnami package in the ubuntu server, so i restarted apache many times but never the php service, so i did it with this command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```

and it works, i dont know wich configuration files failed but nevermind, now it works.. :)